# Documenting a class in an AMD module with JSDoc 3

Tags: javascript, amd, jsdoc3

I'm trying to document a class in an AMD JavaScript module using JSDoc 3. Here's my code, based on the example in the documentation [here](http://usejsdoc.org/howto-amd-modules.html#function-that-returns-another-function):

```
/**
 * A module representing a jacket.
 * @module my/jacket
 */
define('my/jacket', function() {
  /**
   * @class
   * @alias module:my/jacket
   */
  function Jacket() {
  }

  /**
   * Open and close your Jacket.
   */
  Jacket.prototype.zip = function() {
  };

  return Jacket;
});
```

The output this produces looks like this:

> **Class: module:my/jacket**
>
> module:my/jacket
>
> `new module:my/jacket()`

but I'd like it to read:

> **Class: Jacket**
>
> Jacket
>
> `new Jacket()`

Is there a way to do this? I'm using jsdoc 3.4.1.

I've tried changing `@class` to `@class Jacket`, which almost works: the class appears with the right name, but the documentation of the `zip` method is not generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to set the class (function) name using the `@alias` tag instead of the module name:

```
/**
 * A module representing a jacket.
 * @module my/jacket
 */
define('my/jacket', function() {
  /**
   * @class
   * @alias Jacket
   */
  function Jacket() {
  }

  /**
   * Open and close your Jacket.
   */
  Jacket.prototype.zip = function() {
  };

  return Jacket;
});
```

This produces the desired output:

> **Class: Jacket**
>
> Jacket
>
> `new module:Jacket()`

together with the `zip` method documentation.